# Implementing roles & permissions in Laravel 5 (with github/romanbican/roles)

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-5

I'm wanting to use a pre existing package, probably [This one](https://github.com/romanbican/roles), but I'm open to others. My question is, when exactly would I create the roles? Because they're going to get saved to the database, I don't want it to run every time it initializes or anything like that, so how would I create all the roles and permissions just once? Is there an equivalent to Migrations I can use, or should I just use a migration to create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database structure of this package is created during installation. According to documentation the last point is:

> Run migrations.
>
> $ php artisan migrate

Package contains 5 migration files for 5 different tables.

You assign specific roles to specific users in your application. How to do it - it is totally up to you. If you have admin panel/dashboard for managing users - it is a great place. A role is just a kind of user property.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted some solid confirmation, but kind of realised where I was going wrong as I wrote it, as before I hadn't been including them in a migration.